# Java/Kotlin convert numbers into a better string representation ("aa" notation)

Tags: java, kotlin, biginteger, notation

I am currently programming a point system for players in my app. Since these points can get very large very quickly, I would like to have a system that converts a BigInteger into a better representation (see below).

Examples:

```
1000 -> 1k
5555555 -> 5.55m
1000000000000000000 -> 1ab
```

units: k, m, b, t, aa, ab, ac ...

I really doesn't have anything yet, as I don't know where to start.
I found [this](https://gram.gs/gramlog/formatting-big-numbers-aa-notation/), but it's in C# and I don't really know how to convert it into java/kotlin.

Maybe someone can give me an entry point or just a a code snippet which does that? :D

*sorry for the bad english*

Comment: Why aa, ab, ac when there is [quadrillion, quintillion, sextillion, etc](https://www.thoughtco.com/zeros-in-million-billion-trillion-2312346)? I've seen them abbreviated with one or two letters in many games. On the other hand, if you want something systematic that scales infinitely, it would probably be better to use the scientific notation rather than an ad-hoc aa, ab, ac

Comment: I still want the user to understand the number and with the scientific notation it's very hard to understand the number. I also can't just continue with quadrillion, quintillion etc .. because 1. the user probably doesn't know the units anymore and letters like "q" would be doubled and I don't want the string to get to long with the full unit-name.

Comment: *I still want the user to understand the number and with the scientific notation it's very hard to understand the number* - I precisely believe the opposite of this, `1.23e18` is clearer than an inexistent unit. *the user probably doesn't know the units anymore* - `aa` is a unit that doesn't exist, so no one knows it at all, so you might as well use the actual unit for this quantity, at least some people will know. *letters like "q" would be doubled and I don't want the string to get too long* - there are other ways to deal with this: q/Q, or qa/qi. Anything is better than aa/ab.

Comment: but the user understands that "aa" is bigger then for example "t" and smaller then "ab"

Comment: take a look at this: https://gram.gs/gramlog/formatting-big-numbers-aa-notation/ and maybe you will understand me

Comment: I am with @Joffrey on this. This `aa` notation is unreadable unless you are very familiar with it (which I bet not many users will be). Why do you think that anyone will better understand `that "aa" is bigger than for example "t" and smaller than "ab"` than the well-known battle-tested scientific notation? No regular user will ever understand the `aa` notation unless you add next to it exactly the same link that you shared in the previous comment.

Comment: @Joffrey & @João Dias, I 100% agree with you that `aa` is not the best for most cases and that scientific notation is better. But in other cases `aa` notation is the actual expected norm, for example in idle clickers games. It doesn't matter if we agree the notation or not, people expect that to be implemented. And if OP needs help with that specific thing, then OP needs help with that specific thing.

Comment: @DerNoob The linked page complains that neither scientific notation nor S.I. prefixes are widely used or understood (which I dispute) — but then invents another yet notation is which far _less_ widely used and understood! (Also an inconsistent hybrid, less concise than SI prefixes, and needs more existing knowledge than scientific notation.) Unless this is a fixed, unchangeable requirement I'd strongly suggest [S.I. prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Prefixes) or [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explicitly not a solution, but only a quick attempt to translate the code on gram.gs/gramlog/formatting-big-numbers-aa-notation to Kotlin:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat
import kotlin.math.floor
import kotlin.math.log
import kotlin.math.pow

fun formatNumber(value: Double): String {

  val charA = 'a'.code

  val units = mapOf(
    0 to "",
    1 to "K",
    2 to "M",
    3 to "B",
    4 to "T"
  )

  if (value < 1.0) {
    return "0"
  }

  val n = log(value, 1000.0).toInt()
  val m = value / 1000.0.pow(n)
  
  var unit = "";

  if (n < units.count()) {
    unit = units[n]!!
  } else {
    val unitInt = n - units.count()
    val secondUnit = unitInt % 26
    val firstUnit = unitInt / 26
    unit = (firstUnit + charA).toChar().toString() + (secondUnit + charA).toChar().toString()
  }

  return DecimalFormat("#.##").format(floor(m * 100) / 100) + unit

}

println((formatNumber(1.0)))
println((formatNumber(1_000.0)))
println((formatNumber(1_000_000.0)))
println((formatNumber(1_000_000_000.0)))
println((formatNumber(1_000_000_000_000.0)))
println((formatNumber(1_000_000_000_000_000.0)))
println((formatNumber(1_000_000_000_000_000_000.0)))
```